# Malloc Error 2372 When Using Two Seperate Instances Of One Class

Tags: c++, class, malloc

for clarity this bug is from a program for a school assignment but the bug itself is related to problems with malloc rather than understanding the assignment. In the assignment I am only using one instance of this class so the question is mostly for future reference. The problem I am running into occurs when I utilize 2 different instances of my Heap class declared here:

**a4.h**

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std; 

    /*
            Class Declarations
    ********************************************************************
    */

    // A Heap implemented with a growing array

    class Heap{

    public:
        Heap(); 
        ~Heap(); 
        void insert ( int item ); 
        int remove(); 
        void printheap(); 

    private:
        void trickleup   ( int pos ); 
        void trickledown ( int pos ); 
        void swap    ( int pos1 , int pos2 ); 

        int* A; 
        int size; 
        int capacity; 
    }; 




    /*
            Class Methods
    *********************************************************************
    */

    // For Heap

    Heap::Heap(){
        A = NULL; 
        size = 0; 
        capacity = 0; 
    }

    Heap::~Heap(){

        delete A; 
    }

    void Heap::insert ( int item ){

        if ( size == capacity ){
            int* newpointer = new int[(capacity*2)+1]; 
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) newpointer[i] = A[i]; 
            delete A; 
            A = newpointer; 
        }

        A[size] = item; 
        size += 1; 
        trickleup (size-1); 
        return; 
    }

    int Heap::remove(){

        size -= 1; 
        int temp = A[0]; 
        swap ( 0 , size ); 
        trickledown (0); 
        return temp; 
    }

    void Heap::printheap(){

        cout << "Root -> [ "; 
        for (int i = 0; i <  size; i++) cout << A[i] << " "; 
        cout << "]\n"; 
        return; 
    }

    void Heap::trickleup ( int pos ){

        int p0 = pos; 
        int p1 = (pos-1)/2; 

        if ( p0 == 0 ){
            trickledown (0); 
            return; 
        }
        if ( A[p0] > A[p1] ){
            swap ( p0 , p1 ); 
            trickleup ( p1 ); 
        }
        else trickledown (p0); 
        return; 
    }

    void Heap::trickledown ( int pos ){

        int p0 = pos; 
        int p1 = (2*pos)+1; 
        int p2 = (2*pos)+2; 

        if ( p1 >= size ) return; 
        if ( p2 >= size ){
            if ( A[p0] < A[p1] ) swap ( p0 , p1 ); 
            return; 
        }

        bool f1 = ( A[p0] < A[p1] );    
        bool f2 = ( A[p0] < A[p2] );    

        if ( (A[p1] >= A[p2]) && f1 ){
            swap ( p0 , p1 ); 
            trickledown ( p1 ); 
        }
        else if ( (A[p1] < A[p2]) && f2 ){
            swap ( p0 , p2 ); 
            trickledown ( p2 ); 
        }
        return; 
    }

    void Heap::swap ( int pos1 , int pos2 ){

        int temp = A[pos1]; 
        A[pos1] = A[pos2]; 
        A[pos2] = temp; 
        return; 
    }
```

The only time I use `new` to request memory is in the insert function.

The problem occurs when I run my test program compiled from **htest.cpp** and run both the sections for the h1 test and the h2 test. If I only run one of the two tests the problem does not occur. Here is the test program:

**htest.cpp**

```
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <iostream> 
    #include "a4.h"

    using namespace std; 

    int main(){

        cout << "\nCreating h1 And h2\n\n"; 

        Heap* h1 = new Heap(); 
        Heap* h2 = new Heap(); 

        cout << "\nAdding 0-6 To h1\n\n"; 

        h1->insert ( 0 ); cout << "h1: "; h1->printheap(); 
        h1->insert ( 1 ); cout << "h1: "; h1->printheap(); 
        h1->insert ( 2 ); cout << "h1: "; h1->printheap(); 
        h1->insert ( 3 ); cout << "h1: "; h1->printheap(); 
        h1->insert ( 4 ); cout << "h1: "; h1->printheap(); 
        h1->insert ( 5 ); cout << "h1: "; h1->printheap(); 
        h1->insert ( 6 ); cout << "h1: "; h1->printheap(); 

        cout << "\nRemoving All Elements From h1\n\n"; 

        cout << "Removed: " << h1->remove(); 
        cout << "  h1: "; h1->printheap(); 
        cout << "Removed: " << h1->remove(); 
        cout << "  h1: "; h1->printheap(); 
        cout << "Removed: " << h1->remove(); 
        cout << "  h1: "; h1->printheap(); 
        cout << "Removed: " << h1->remove(); 
        cout << "  h1: "; h1->printheap(); 
        cout << "Removed: " << h1->remove(); 
        cout << "  h1: "; h1->printheap(); 
        cout << "Removed: " << h1->remove(); 
        cout << "  h1: "; h1->printheap(); 
        cout << "Removed: " << h1->remove(); 
        cout << "  h1: "; h1->printheap(); 

        cout << "\nAdding 6-0 To h2\n\n"; 

        h2->insert ( 6 ); cout << "h2: "; h2->printheap(); 
        h2->insert ( 5 ); cout << "h2: "; h2->printheap(); 
        h2->insert ( 4 ); cout << "h2: "; h2->printheap(); 
        h2->insert ( 3 ); cout << "h2: "; h2->printheap(); 
        h2->insert ( 2 ); cout << "h2: "; h2->printheap(); 
        h2->insert ( 1 ); cout << "h2: "; h2->printheap(); 
        h2->insert ( 0 ); cout << "h2: "; h2->printheap(); 

        cout << "\nRemoving All Elements From h2\n\n"; 

        cout << "Removed: " << h2->remove(); 
        cout << "  h2: "; h2->printheap(); 
        cout << "Removed: " << h2->remove(); 
        cout << "  h2: "; h2->printheap(); 
        cout << "Removed: " << h2->remove(); 
        cout << "  h2: "; h2->printheap(); 
        cout << "Removed: " << h2->remove(); 
        cout << "  h2: "; h2->printheap(); 
        cout << "Removed: " << h2->remove(); 
        cout << "  h2: "; h2->printheap(); 
        cout << "Removed: " << h2->remove(); 
        cout << "  h2: "; h2->printheap(); 
        cout << "Removed: " << h2->remove(); 
        cout << "  h2: "; h2->printheap(); 

        cout << "\n"; 

        return 0; 
    }
```

After compiling this program and running it (with the GNU C++ compiler) I get the following output:

**Output**

```
    Creating h1 And h2


    Adding 0-6 To h1

    h1: Root -> [ 0 ]
    h1: Root -> [ 1 0 ]
    h1: Root -> [ 2 0 1 ]
    h1: Root -> [ 3 2 1 0 ]
    h1: Root -> [ 4 3 1 0 2 ]
    h1: Root -> [ 5 3 4 0 2 1 ]
    h1: Root -> [ 6 3 5 0 2 1 4 ]

    Removing All Elements From h1

    Removed: 6  h1: Root -> [ 5 3 4 0 2 1 ]
    Removed: 5  h1: Root -> [ 4 3 1 0 2 ]
    Removed: 4  h1: Root -> [ 3 2 1 0 ]
    Removed: 3  h1: Root -> [ 2 0 1 ]
    Removed: 2  h1: Root -> [ 1 0 ]
    Removed: 1  h1: Root -> [ 0 ]
    Removed: 0  h1: Root -> [ ]

    Adding 6-0 To h2

    htest: malloc.c:2372: sysmalloc: Assertion `(old_top == (((mbinptr) (((char *) &((av)->bins[((1) - 1) * 2])) - __builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd)))) && old_size == 0) || ((unsigned long) (old_size) >= (unsigned long)((((__builtin_offsetof (struct malloc_chunk, fd_nextsize))+((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1)) & ~((2 *(sizeof(size_t))) - 1))) && ((old_top)->size & 0x1) && ((unsigned long) old_end & pagemask) == 0)' failed.
    Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am wondering why the error appears as it doesn't seem like I am doing anything illegal with requesting memory. I would really appreciate it if someone could try to explain the problem clearly as I only have about one year of C++ experience.

*Edit: Changed the destructor Function to not delete size and capacity and added a delete A line to the insert function before re-sizing the array.

Comment: `delete &size` and `delete &capacity` are wrong. Remove them.

Comment: This is quite 'illegal': `delete &size; 
        delete &capacity;` since both are defined as `int` members.

Comment: You could use `valgrind` to try and get more detailed information about the problem.

Comment: `void Heap::insert ( int item )` does not `delete A;` before `A = newpointer;`

Comment: The function bodies should not be in the header. If two different units include this header, it causes undefined behaviour (ODR violation). You should either: (a) put function bodies in a `.cpp` file, or (b) put them in the class definition, or (c) mark the bodies `inline`

Comment: Using `vector` for the underlying buffer would save you a lot of drama. As things stand your class violates the Rule of 3 so it would be good to delete the copy-constructor and copy-assignment operator to prevent inadvertant copying (e.g. currently `Heap h = Heap();` causes UB).

Comment: The `Heap::swap` implementation could be `std::swap(A[pos1], A[pos2]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sad that I didn't spot this one before. I'll throw myself onto my sword after answering.

`Heap::insert` never sets `capacity`. It stays 0, so inserts after the first do not trigger `if (size == capacity)` and do not resize `A`. As a result, `A` is run out of bounds and trashes the heap (the the memory heap, not the class `Heap`).

I recommend a small edit:

```
void Heap::insert(int item)
{
    if (size == capacity)
    {
        capacity = (capacity * 2) + 1; // Note: many tests have shown that 1.5 is a 
                                       // better expansion factor than 2.
        int* newpointer = new int[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            newpointer[i] = A[i];
        delete A;
        A = newpointer;
    }

    A[size] = item;
    size += 1;
    trickleup(size - 1);
    return;
}
```

In addition

```
Heap* h1 = new Heap();
Heap* h2 = new Heap();
```

do not need to be dynamically allocated and can be defined as

```
Heap h1;
Heap h2;
```

Among other advantages temporary allocation brings, such as improved spacial locality, this does not require the programmer to `delete` `h1` and `h2`, something that is currently not done.

Now if you will excuse me, I must find where I left my sword.

Comment: This fix worked and after seeing such a simple mistake I feel like I need to re-examine my brain and eyes for not noticing this. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Comment: Don't feel too bad. 12 other people, at least four of them pretty darn good at this stuff, didn't see it either. Until you made your edit, I was pretty sure that `delete &size` and `delete &capacity` were the sole culprits. Recommend spending a bit of time getting to know whatever debugger comes with your development environment. Stepping through the code would have spotted the problem a lot faster than I did.